# svnkit authentication problem with ntlm in Java

Tags: java, svn, ntlm, svnkit

I have a `servers` file on my computer with `http-auth-types = Negotiate;ntlm;basic`

The following Java program with svnkit 1.10.2 should connect to a repository :

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) throws SVNException
  {
    SVNClientManager clientManager = SVNClientManager.newInstance();

    ISVNAuthenticationManager manager = SVNWCUtil.createDefaultAuthenticationManager();

    clientManager.setAuthenticationManager(manager);
    SVNURL repositoryURL = SVNURL.parseURIEncoded(args[0]);
    SVNRepository repository = clientManager.createRepository(repositoryURL, true);

    Collection<SVNDirEntry> contentOfFolder = repository.getDir("", SVNRevision.HEAD.getNumber(),
        null, SVNDirEntry.DIRENT_ALL, (Collection<SVNDirEntry>) null);

    System.out.println(contentOfFolder);
  }
```

Unfortunately, I get

```
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNAuthenticationException: svn: E170001: Authentication required for ...
```

What am I doing wrong? Do I somehow need to tell svnkit to use ntlm?